# I want to create a Telegram chat bot using python version 3.11.2

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am using python version 3.11.2 pip version 23.3.1 and bot-telegram version 25
My coding is like this:

bot.py

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters

load_dotenv()

bot_token = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')

bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)


def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                             text="Halo! Selamat datang di bot Telegram saya.")


def puisi(update, context):
    text_puisi = "bercahayalah jiga kamu ingin dicintai setiap lawan jenis. "
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=text_puisi)


def pantun(update, context):
    text_pantun = "jalan-jalan ke jakarta barat, pulangnya beli sempolan. kalau kamu tidak ingin bersahabat, mari kita pacaran"
    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=text_pantun)


def echo(update, context):
    message = update.message.text
    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=message)
    print(f"pesan dari user: {message}")


updater = Updater(token=bot_token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('puisi', puisi))
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('pantun', pantun))

dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.text & ~filters.command, echo))

updater.start_polling()

updater.idle()
```

when I run the program I get an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\telegram-bot-python-main\bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rezae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 264, in __init__
    HTTPXRequest() if get_updates_request is None else get_updates_request,
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rezae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_httpxrequest.py", line 137, in __init__
    self._client = self._build_client()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rezae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\request\_httpxrequest.py", line 162, in _build_client
    return httpx.AsyncClient(**self._client_kwargs)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rezae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1397, in __init__
    self._transport = self._init_transport(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rezae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1445, in _init_transport
    return AsyncHTTPTransport(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rezae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_transports\default.py", line 275, in __init__
    self._pool = httpcore.AsyncConnectionPool(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: AsyncConnectionPool.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'http1'
```

please help me to fix it I really appreciate it when anyone wants to help me

I want the program to run according to its function without errors. If there are any errors, please let me know, thank you